# How to remove conditional incident edges from my graph?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph, graph-theory

I have MST graph and I'm trying to cluster it according to the following:

1. Sorting graph edges in descending order based on their weights.
2. Starting from the edge with max weight, for each edge, we will remove the edge in case of:

   **current edge weight > (sum(adjacent edges weights)/num of adjacent edges)**.

In other words, we will remove each edge that has a weight greater than avg of incident/adjacent edges weights.

Let's take a look at the following example:

[image]

Staring from edge [9-12] which has max edge weight in the graph, edges [11-12, 5-9, 8-9] are incident/adjacent edges to edge [9-12] so the edge 9-12 has weight = 7 should be removed because the avg incident edges weight = (0+3+1)/3 = 1.33 and so on for other edges.

After Googling to find a solution I found **delete.edges()** and I use it to complete another clustering approach which based on Edge Weight Threshold as the following

```
g <- delete.edges(mst, which(E(mst)$weight > EWT))
where EWT = [My Threshold]
```

But I don't know if I can use it to delete edges according to incident/adjacent edges.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] and then use the [edit] facilities to improve this question with a specific example and your version of the "correct answer".

Comment: Apart from giving a reproducible example, you should ask a single question. Edge deletion is one thing and extracting connected components is another.